# How can I create new columns having key names from dictionary in same dataframe?

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

I try to use your code in order to transform this :
[column of dictionaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONpVn.png)

into 2 new columns : score and winner

But when I use this code :

```
data = data.join(
    pd.DataFrame.from_records(
        data["score"].mask(data.score.isna(), {}).tolist()
    ).add_prefix("score_")
)

print(data.head())
```

The print give me this : [new columns added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiTIl.png)

In clear, I have a new column for every characters in the dictionary.

Could you help me with this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass col of dicts as array of dicts like:

```
d = [{'score': [1], 'winner': "L"}, {'score': [1], 'winner': "W"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Out (df.head()):

```
score   winner
0   [1] L
1   [1] W
```

And than use to unzip array elems (should be int's): `df["score"] = df["score"].apply(sum)`